# Hive Table Creation From Shell - Dynamic Table Name

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I am working on a Hadoop edge node, running a bash shell script that calls two R script files in sequence.  These R scripts run analyses on current data then save a CSV file with the name format "analysis_YYYYMMDD.csv" with today's date to HDFS.

I need to be able to have this CSV file available as a Hive table.  I also append this data to an existing table.  As it stands, I take the daily CSV and run the following code in Hive CLI:

```
create table schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD(col1 string, col2 string, col3 double) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile ;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'analysis_YYYYMMDD.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE 
schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD;

INSERT INTO TABLE schema.all_analysis SELECT * FROM 
schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD;
```

I would like to include this Hive CLI code in my shell script so I can remove this last manual step.  Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: what is the purpose of creating new table if you are appending it to another table already?

Comment: I suppose it's not essential, thus far I've been doing it as a redundancy play (e.g., if I accidentally drop table schema.all_analysis I can rebuild it via the other tables.)  I understand the shell script would be much easier if I just saved the file as "analysis.csv" and appended.

Comment: if you are worried about dropping data,  why not use external table. and just drop the files on location. you don't need to do `LOAD DATA INPATH`

Comment: I have a separate postgresql db that I connect to in the rscript.  I can easily write a table schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD in postgresql within the rscript for safekeeping, then just append to schema.all_analysis within the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a template for creation script and replace it each day with current day at appropriate places.

You may then  use `hive` commandline with `-f` option to run the whole script file

```
#!/bin/bash
curr_dt=$(date +%Y%m%d) #get date in YYYYMMDD format

cat >daily_sql_"${curr_dt}".sql <<'EOL'
create table schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD(col1 string, col2 string, col3 double) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile ;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'analysis_YYYYMMDD.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE 
schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD;

INSERT INTO TABLE schema.all_analysis SELECT * FROM 
schema.analysis_YYYYMMDD;
EOL

if [ -n "$curr_dt" ];then #if defined
 perl -pi -e "s/YYYYMMDD/$curr_dt/"  daily_sql_"${curr_dt}".sql 
                                             #replace date format to $curr_dt
fi

if [ -f daily_sql_"${curr_dt}".sql ]
then
   hive -f daily_sql_"${curr_dt}".sql
fi
```